# can i generate Stripe Checkout Payment link without API libraries?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Is it possible to generate a payment link by curl to Strip without using  Strip PHP library??

Example :
Send parameters like (amount, currency, item details, callback, return and cancel url .. etc)  to stripe api link as (GET) or (Post) then generate a payment link and return with a payment status and transaction.

Thats all ..

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a Payment Link using cURL : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create.

However, I strongly recommend using the stripe SDK libraries. The library is basically a wrapper for the underlying HTTP requests with useful features like automatic retries, idempotency keys and robust error handling.